# Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasInputDevices , when running tests using ghostdriver

Tags: webdriver, maven-3, phantomjs

I am trying to run my webdriver test cases using ghostdriver (Phantomjs) but that's giving error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasInputDevices`. 
Everything seems fine to me but I dont understand why there is error.
OS - WIN7
Coding - JAVA 1.7 
Framework : java1.7+testng6.5.2+maven3
Selenium-java version 2.35.0

**testcase**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ghosttest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void testing() {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); 
        caps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
        "D:/dumps/phantomjs-1.9.1-windows/phantomjs-1.9.1-windows/phantomjs.exe");
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        String Logintext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Maps")).getText();
        System.out.println(Logintext);

    }
}
```

**maven dependency for ghostdriver**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that ghostdriver is not [compatible with Selenium 2.35](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/260).

If you change your dependency to 2.34 you will be fine. You will have to wait for a new PhantomJSDriver unfortunately if you specifically need Selenium 2.35.

Currently the latest version of phantomjsdriver is 1.0.4 as well, you had 1.0.3.

Comment: this is so mean to say but I managed to fix it before your answer. However problem stil not solved as i am getting this error "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.34.0', revision: '11cd0ef93615408e0b6b3bfa28defe125906461a', time: '2013-08-06 11:43:14' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.5.0-21-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_25' Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver"

Comment: I think you have a problem with your path. I am using Linux though and in my case I installed PhantomJS through nodejs, with `npm -g install phantomjs`. Then it just worked, I didn't need to specify any binary, but of course node added it to the system path. You could try doing adding it yourself in Windows PATH if it isn't already. I would then try removing the capabilities configuration and just trying the driver directly. I think it does support JavaScript automatically anyway.

Comment: I think I'll get success if I do it that way i.e. adding node to the system path but I don't know how to do. Could you please share piece of code.

Comment: For those who are not using GhostDriver and still facing the same issue  Please look at the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763752/hasinputdevices-is-located-at-org-openqa-selenium-interactions-but-it-is-st)