# "HasInputDevices" is located at "/org/openqa/selenium/interactions" but it is still looking at "/org/openqa/selenium/"

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I want to run my `WebDriver` test cases on `Chrome` on remote `Ubuntu` server. I have installed latest `Chrome` on that server but I've been getting these errors,when I used this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Error1:
`The driver is not executable: /usr/bin/chromedriver` to correct I made it executable using `sudo 777 chromedriver` then I got 
Error2:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally` to fix this I updated `selenium jar dependencies` to `2.40.0` and since then, I've been getting
Error3:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasInputDevices`
**Query:** Now I know that `HasInputDevices` has been moved to `org/openqa/selenium/Interactions/` then why it is still looking in old directory path `org/openqa/selenium/HasInputDevices`. How to let it find at its actual directory.

1. I have updated dependencies. 
2. I have tried to use `mvn install` so that it download what is written in `pom.xml`
but it's looking in old directory.
How to resolve this error, I don't want to downgrade selenium APIs, because then Chrome exits unexpectedly.

Comment: Seems like you have a conflict of jars going on - and what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: /usr/bin$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 33.0.1750.152

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, getting ClassCastException where HasInputDevices was incompatible with FirefoxDriver.

Solved by changing the import to another package:
**From**

> import org.openqa.selenium.Mouse;

**To**

> import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Mouse;

The exact error stack I encountered was:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and way to resolve was next:
remove all unused dependencies from POM.xml
for example if u use only FirefoxDriver and in POM.xml there are anothers one (Chrome, Common, remote) delete them

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which worked for me. I was using a dependency which had a transitive dependency on selenium-remote-driver version 2.34.0, remove this dependency and it will work.This dependency was:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
 <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**OR**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
<artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
<version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```