# NoClassDefFoundError: while there is maven dependencie and jar in repo

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Can anyone explain to me what is the reason of the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    ...
```

It occurs when Im trying to use `rg.seleniumhq.selenium` selenium-support library, I have it described in POM.XML

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.33.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and jar is displayed in external libraries,
any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class  is part of the `selenium-api.jar`. add this also to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.33.0</version>
</dependency>
```

this jar contains the class `org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, but where did u find it in log??

Comment: @abrakadabrda i have googled, which jar contains the class.

Comment: but page factory class is located in selenium-support library

Comment: @abrakadabrda but you get the classnot foundexcpetion for `org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices`

Comment: This resolves the issue but does explain "the reason of the exception" (which is the question being asked).

Comment: @mfulton26 Why you think it is not a answer of the question?

Comment: @Jens The question is not "How do I resolve this issue?" it is "Why am I getting this issue?" See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35203213/3255152).

Comment: @mfulton26 Your answer is wrong. I can see no dependency to an selenium api in the question of OP. And as you can see the answer is accepted by op, so it solves the Problem and i think it is the answer.

Comment: @Jens `selenium-support` already depends on `selenium-api` as I explain in my answer. [abrakadabrda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5872174/abrakadabrda) shouldn't need to declare a dependency on `support-api` as it is a transitive dependency hence his question here. If you create an empty Maven project and depend on `selenium-support` Maven will pull in `selenium-api` and all of the other dependencies automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have a dependency conflict because [`selenium-support`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.seleniumhq.selenium%7Cselenium-support%7C2.33.0%7Cjar) already depends on [`selenium-api`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.seleniumhq.selenium%7Cselenium-api%7C2.33.0%7Cjar) (see [`selenium-support-2.33.0.pom`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.33.0/selenium-support-2.33.0.pom)) but somewhere in your dependency tree there is a conflicting version `selenium-api` that is being used instead.

Read [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin – Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

Then run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=selenium-api` for your Maven module to find your conflict.

See also the answers to the following questions on Stack Overflow:

- ["HasInputDevices" is located at "/org/openqa/selenium/interactions" but it is still looking at "/org/openqa/selenium/"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22763752/3255152)
- [Conflicting library version in a java maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19659425/3255152)

You will need to resolve the dependency conflict. One way to do that is to use [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35196923/3255152) and explicitly declare the dependency on the version you want but the conflict will still be there and you may have other conflicts that you don't know of yet. I recommend using [dependency convergence](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) with the [Maven Enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4993851/3255152) to detect existing conflicts and to avoid introducing more conflicts in the future.